# tableView change height in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have dynamic cell count in my tableView, how can I change tableView height?

I try, but it's not work:

```
self.tableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(height)
```

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using the `autolayouts` then below code would work:

```
    func adjustTableViewHeight() {
        var height = tableView.contentSize.height
        let maxHeight = (tableView.superview?.frame.size.height)! - self.tableView.frame.origin.y

       if height > maxHeight {
           height = maxHeight
       }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { 
            var frame = self.tableView.frame
            frame.size.height = height
            self.tableView.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

If you are using `autolayouts` then use this:

```
    func adjustTableViewHeight() {
        var height = tableView.contentSize.height
        let maxHeight = (tableView.superview?.frame.size.height)! - self.tableView.frame.origin.y

       if height > maxHeight {
           height = maxHeight
       }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { 
           //Assuming 'tableViewHeightConstraint` is an IBOutlet from your storyboard/XIB
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
            self.tableView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Please up-vote it and accept it as answer.